# Facebook Login on Android App

Tags: android, facebook

I have seen numerous stackoverflow posts but none of them seem to be helping me in this problem.

When I try to login using facebook, the facebook app opens, asks for permissions and then when I click OK, everything goes into background. There is nothing in the logs.

Things that I have already tried:

I have created app on Facebook developer console

- Added Android as platform on Settings page, added package name, class name and generated key hash. Then i also added the key hash from the logcat error with = at the end.
- I have added my email address in contact, and made my app go live in Status & Review.
- I have installed and logged in to Facebook app on my android device.
- I have tried deleting my debug.keystore, and generating new hash
- I have tried deleting Facebook developer app and creating it from scratch
- I am using LoginManager to sign-in to facebook from my android app.

Here is my code for login:

```
private void loginWithFacebook() {
    final LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginManager.registerCallback(
            callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.e("WelcomeScreen", "onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.e("WelcomeScreen", "onCancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Log.e("WelcomeScreen", "onError");
                }
            }
    );
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
}
```

I have already done this in onCreate:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: what is the significance of the Activity name in the Facebook developer console? Might that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In my manifest, I had specified noHistory to true for the activity where I was expecting the activity result back from Facebook activity, but since the activity is destroyed once it launches another activity, the app was shutting down. Removing the hoHistory resolved the issue.